# iPhone AVAssetWriter video hangs quicktime player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, media

I have a video that's written using AVAssetWriter w/ kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB and the AVVideoCodecH264 codec.  I generate my own frames @ 25 fps for the first pass at the video.  I then combine this video only asset with audio using AVAssetExportSession.

The video uploads to Facebook and plays just fine.  It also works in VLC on a mac.  However the quicktime player on the mac 10.0 ( 128) just hangs with the beachball of death.

VLC shows 2 streams:

- Stream 1: video, H264 - MPEG-4 AVC ( part 10 ), 320 x 400, 25 fps
- Stream 2: audio, apple lossless audio codec ( alac ), mono, 44100 Hz, 16 bits

Why doesn't quicktime like this video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by switching from kAudioFormatAppleLossless to kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC.